# Angular Router always get back to Main Page

Tags: angular, routes, navigateurl

I've got a problem with Angular Router (Angular 11). That's my routing below:

```
{path: '', redirectTo: '/zaloguj', pathMatch: 'full'}
{path: 'zaloguj', component: LoginComponent}
{path: 'orzeczenia', component: ApiComponent}
{path: 'orzeczenia/:id', component: ShowDataComponent}
{path: 'kontakt', component: ContactComponent}
{path: 'konto', component: DashboardComponent}
{path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
```

I created the function (below) in one of my component:

```
showVerdict(): any {
this.router.navigate(['/kontakt']);
```

}

When I use this function, Angular goes to the Kontakt Route (ContactComponent), but after maybe 1 sec, redirects to MainPage. I changed the route to for example "konto", etc. however, the problem still occurs. Please help me!

Comment: can you post ContactComponent code

Comment: Can i ask you change place of path: ‘’ and put it before path: ‘**’

Comment: Add code for ContactComponent here. I think that component is the culprit. @iCoders

Comment: @MehranBeiglou Routes are matched by first match found strategy so order or routes is not issue here.

Comment: Can you create short stackblitz example for this? I might be able to help you there

Comment: @Kshitij i know what you say but generally is not correct put path: ' ' at the top of the routes array

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem. It was trivial. I added the click event to an "a link", but I forgot to remove href="#"... Now, everything is fine.